# How to set height and width dimensions when sending a request with Requests-HTML

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, python-requests-html

I am using requests-html to get data on this website: https://rl.insider.gg/en/pc. Whenever I send a request to the site and attempt to render the Javascript, I keep getting redirected to the mobile site.

I did some investigating and found out that the site will redirect you to the mobile site when your browser width is **<1250px**. I also made a temporary API that returns the dimensions of the request, and found that Requests-HTML sends the request in a browser of side **800px X 600px.**

Here is my current code:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

url = 'https://rl.insider.gg/en/pc'
session = HTMLSession()

r = session.get(url)
r.html.render(sleep=2, timeout=1000)

#RL Insider redirects to mobile site when the width is less than 1250px
#Request HTML sends the request in a browser that is 800px X 600px, I need to change that

print(r.html.html)
```

Does anyone know if there are some headers or values that I can pass in the request, which will allow me to change the dimensions of the Requests-HTML browser window ?

Answer (score 0):

```
class CustomHTMLSession(HTMLSession):
    def __init__(self, window_width, window_height, **kwargs):
        super(HTMLSession, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.window_width = window_width
        self.window_height = window_height
        self.__browser_args = kwargs.get("browser_args", ["--no-sandbox"])

    @property
    def browser(self):
        if not hasattr(self, "_browser"):
            self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
            if self.loop.is_running():
                raise RuntimeError(
                    "Cannot use HTMLSession within an existing event loop. Use AsyncHTMLSession instead.")
            self._browser = self.loop.run_until_complete(
                pyppeteer.launch(
                    ignoreHTTPSErrors=not (self.verify), headless=True,                    
                    defaultViewport={'width': self.window_width, 'height': self.window_height},
                    args=self.__browser_args))

        return self._browser
```

The window width and height are not exposed in HTMLSession constructor. You can use above code to create a CustomHTMLSession which can pass the window width and height correctly while creating browser boject.

Note: Passing `--window-size="width,height"` in browser_args, does not work.